# Which cities should I visit in China to feel and live the three kingdoms era?

Tags: china, history, turkish-citizens, temples, china-railway

I am really interested in the three kingdoms era (Wei, Shu, Wu) in China. Next year in September I wish to go to China for my honeymoon. My primary purpose is to visit the temples dedicated to especially Guan Yu and Zhang Fei, and also Liu Bei and Zhuge Liang.

I would also like to see some places (like museums, temples etc.) about Cao Cao, or the Wei kingdom in general.

It is hard to find information about these temples. Where are these temples dedicated to Guan Yu, Zhang Fei etc.

I would also like to see some performances about the three kingdoms era, if there are any. (For example operas, shows etc.)

Also I would very much like to learn fighting skills, try some traditional weapons. But I don't think I can do these in two-weeks time.

I think the places I am looking for, will be between Beijing and Chengdu. If I am correct I can arrive to either cities (I will come from Turkey) and then I will leave from the other city for Bali to continue my honeymoon.

The distances between cities are huge so probably I will have to stick to high speed trains. So I probably will not be able to go to remote cities which do not have high speed train coverage.

Time is short, and there is much I want to do. So what do you suggest? Which cities should I visit? How can I travel between cities? Where can I find the temples and other places I am looking for? I would be glad if anyone can advise me a route.

Comment: Hi @Alptugay, and welcome. We've sort of got a rule here that we don't act as travel agents / route planners - each person is so individual, that offering recommendations are too broad and there's no one correct answer.  As a result (see the [help]) this question is likely to be put on hold shortly, if not changed.  However, I welcome you to try our [chat] - members like hippietrail have been to China and recommendations are encouraged in the chat room!

Comment: Hİ @MarkMayo , I hope at least I can learn some temple names and adresses. Thanks for your info. If my question gets closed I will try the chat.